# Mixed scale on a ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I would like to make a plot (preferably with ggplot2), where the x-axis has different scaling.
More precisely I want my scale to be logarithmic from approximately 0.001 to 0.05 and non-logaritmic from 0.05 to 1.0

My current code for the plot is:

```
ggplot(DF, aes(x=DF$RAW.PVAL, col=DF$sample))+stat_ecdf()+geom_abline()+xlim(0,1)+ylim(0,1)+xlab("P Value")+ylab("Frequecy")+ggtitle("Type I error control")+labs(colour="Sample")
```

And here you can see the result:

[Type1ErrorControl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNuCa.png)

Is there anyway I can achieve this? I suppose, that I could define a new transformation, but I didn't find any instructions on how to do this.

Thank you in anticipation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own scale, see ([1](http://www.numbertheory.nl/2012/08/14/custom-axis-transformations-in-ggplot2/),[2](https://andrewpwheeler.wordpress.com/2015/07/31/custom-square-root-scale-with-negative-values-in-ggplot2-r/)) for other examples. Here is an example for your particular discontinuous function.

```
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)

MixLogF <- function(x){ 
    if(x < 0.05){r <- log(x) - log(0.05) + 0.05}
    else {r <- x}
    return(r) 
}
MixLogV <- Vectorize(MixLogF)
InvMixLogF <- function(x){ 
    if(x < 0.05){r <- exp(x - 0.05 + log(0.05))}
    else {r <- x}
    return(r)
}
InvMixLogV <- Vectorize(InvMixLogF)
MixLogV_trans <- function() trans_new("MixLogV",MixLogV,InvMixLogV,domain = c(0.001, Inf))

y <- (1:100)/100
x <- MixLogV(y)
ExpDat <- data.frame(x,y)
orig <- ggplot(data=ExpDat, aes(x=y,y=y)) + geom_point()
orig
orig + scale_x_continuous(trans="MixLogV", limits=c(0.01, 1), breaks=c(0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05,0.30,0.80))
```

[image]

Agree with eipi10, use with care - could be misleading.

---

For labeling purposes, it may be easier to see the effects the function has on the scale by having equal breaks in the plot space. The example below shows that the upper part is quite squished - you can't have a p-value over 1, which when breaking at 0.05 is the same distance away as `exp(log(0.05) - 0.95)` ~ 0.02.

```
#For nice even breaks
blog <- c(0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04)
blin <- 0.05 + log(0.05) - log(rev(blog))
orig + scale_x_continuous(trans="MixLogV", limits=c(0.01, blin[4]), 
       breaks=c(blog,0.05,blin), labels = format(c(blog,0.05,blin),digits=2,scientific = FALSE))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That was exactly, what I was looking for!
But the two of you are of course right, that such a plot could be misleading.

Answer (score 5):

The plot risks being misleading due to the scale distortion, but...you could plot separate panels for the two x-ranges, one with log scaling and one with linear scaling and then put them together. We'll change the plot margins in order to control the amount of space between the plots and get proper overlap.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

# Fake data
test <- data.frame(x=c(seq(1,100, length.out=20), 101:110), y=1:30)
```

Left plot (x <= 100):

```
p1 = ggplot(test[test$x<=100,], aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
  geom_point(size=2) +
  scale_x_log10(limits=c(1,100), breaks=c(1,5,10, seq(20,100,20))) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0.8,105), ylim=c(0,32), expand=FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,30)) +
  theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0,-0.2,0,0),"lines")) +
  labs(x="")
```

Right plot (x >= 100):

```
p2 = ggplot(test[test$x>=100,], aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
  geom_point(size=2) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(100,110), breaks=seq(100,110,2)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(100,111), ylim=c(0,32), expand=FALSE) +
  theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,-0.2), "lines"),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank()) +
  labs(y="", x="")

grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(p1, p2, widths=c(0.7,0.3), ncol=2),
             textGrob("x-label"), ncol=1, heights=c(0.95,0.05))
```

[image]