# Mixed sacle on a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I used the code below for the mixed scale. The code is from [Mixed scale on a ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34928795/mixed-scale-on-a-ggplot). It works a year ago. But now, it doesn't work, the error message is "Error in if (x < 0.05) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed". How can I fix it?

```
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)

MixLogF <- function(x){ 
    if(x < 0.05){r <- log(x) - log(0.05) + 0.05}
    else {r <- x}
    return(r) 
}
MixLogV <- Vectorize(MixLogF)
InvMixLogF <- function(x){ 
    if(x < 0.05){r <- exp(x - 0.05 + log(0.05))}
    else {r <- x}
    return(r)
}
InvMixLogV <- Vectorize(InvMixLogF)
MixLogV_trans <- function() trans_new("MixLogV",MixLogV,InvMixLogV,domain = c(0.001, Inf))

y <- (1:100)/100
x <- MixLogV(y)
ExpDat <- data.frame(x,y)
orig <- ggplot(data=ExpDat, aes(x=y,y=y)) + geom_point()
orig
orig + scale_x_continuous(trans="MixLogV", limits=c(0.01, 1), breaks=c(0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05,0.30,0.80))
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your code uses an `if-else` instead of the vectorized `ifelse`. While that may have worked in the past, IMHO that wasn't good practice and should at least have thrown a warning. However, this behavior was changed with `R >=4.2.0` and now will raise an error:

> Calling if() or while() with a condition of length greater than one gives an error rather than a warning.

See [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2022/000683.html).

Hence, to fix your issue use `ifelse`:

```r
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)

MixLogF <- function(x) {
  r <- ifelse(x < 0.05, log(x) - log(0.05) + 0.05, x)

  return(r)
}
MixLogV <- Vectorize(MixLogF)
InvMixLogF <- function(x) {
  r <- ifelse(x < 0.05, exp(x - 0.05 + log(0.05)), x)

  return(r)
}
InvMixLogV <- Vectorize(InvMixLogF)
MixLogV_trans <- function() trans_new("MixLogV", MixLogV, InvMixLogV, domain = c(0.001, Inf))

y <- (1:100) / 100
x <- MixLogV(y)
ExpDat <- data.frame(x, y)
orig <- ggplot(data = ExpDat, aes(x = y, y = y)) +
  geom_point()
orig
```

[image]

```r
orig +
  scale_x_continuous(
    trans = "MixLogV",
    limits = c(0.01, 1),
    breaks = c(0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.30, 0.80)
  )
```

[image]